# Could not resolve '___' from state 'home'

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

Why I receive this error? The state.js file is simple

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('theFoodApp')
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function stateConfig($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('concludi', {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/concludi-acquisto',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/pages/carrello/concludi-acquisto/concludi-acquisto.html',
                    controller: 'ConcludiAcquistoController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

The template page exist in the specified path and the controller also.
In other page I've a button with ui-sref="concludi" but when I press it I receive this error

```
Error: Could not resolve 'concludi' from state 'home'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3180)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3108)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4159
    at angular.js:19612
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5964)
    at angular.js:6243
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you're importing `states.js`** into your `index.html`.

Comment: ui.router is imported in app.module.js

Comment: Oh okay, yeah thinking about it that would have raised a different error. Does the uirouter script import appear before your app.module.js import?

Comment: And are you importing state.js?

Comment: Ups. I don't have imported the file in my index. Thank you so much Matthew

Comment: No problem, we got there in the end.